# How to protect your software from being disabled

Tags: c++, windows

We have this client application running on Windows. The core of it is comprised of 2 NT services. The users have admin rights, mostly travelling laptop users. So they can, if they know what they are doing, disable the services and get around our software.

What is "standard" approach to solving this issue?

Any thoughts? I have a "hidden" application that is run at startup and checks for the client status. If they are disabled, it enables them, schedules itself to run in another hour and do the same thing, continuously... If I can hide this application well enough, that should work... Not the prettiest approach...

Other ideas?

Thanks
Reza

Comment: I already hate your application.

Comment: Two answers below, both correct. You could, perhaps, write some kind of system analysis app which will periodically *warn* them that they've disabled the main app, if there's a genuine concern that they'll do so accidentally, and appreciate the reminder to re-enable it. By "periodically" I mean maybe at startup, or perhaps once a day. Anything more and they'll just disable the reminder too.

Comment: How much are you being paid to rape your customers?

Comment: @Noah: How much are you being paid to commit war crimes including, but not limited to, genocide, the use of chemical weapons on civilians, and forcible recruitment of child soldiers, against people who ask bad questions?

Comment: I actually think it's a *good* question because I see lots of question posted here from programmers who think that they need to do something like this.  Their thinking needs to be corrected.

Comment: Soon they will be asking how to write a virus on SO.

Comment: Have you considered asking your users not to turn it off or perhaps writing an app that is decent enough that they don't want to turn it off?

Comment: @Steve - that's surprisingly stupid, even for you.

Comment: @David - You crazy?  Who ever heard of such a thing?

Comment: @Noah Roberts  yes I realise it's a pipe dream......

Comment: @Noah: what, exaggerating to make a point, you mean? Someone would have to have a pretty low IQ to do that, all right.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, you may not want it in most of your software, but it doesn't mean it is not reasonable in some of it.

Comment: @Noah: Are you capable of simply stating information, posing questions, or answering questions without an appeal to ridicule?

Comment: 2Steve JessopL: genocide and chemical weapons pays hourly on per contract basic, obviously. 2All: come on, this question is all right, yet nobody forces you to give free security consulting to OP. whats this buzz about?

Comment: this is a software that a company buys from us to monitor they users activities. It is a choice the customer makes and not us. They want the software and we develop it. As part of customer requirements, this application needs to be tamper proof, even though the customer gives their laptop users admin rights. So it is a commercial product that customers and purchase for what THEY need to do.

Comment: @reza:  The old adage that "the customer is always right" is absolutely wrong.  That's just something salespeople say to potential clients to help close the deal.  But the truth is that customers often ask for something stupid because they know what the end goal is, and that's the first way they thought of to accomplish that goal.  It's the software vendor's responsibility to steer them on the right track.  You are the software expert.  You *should* know what is best.  If you don't, then you've failed both companies.

Answer (score 13):

Let them.

Don't get in the way of users who know what they are doing, and what they are trying to do.

Personally if I installed a piece of software that didn't let me turn it off at will, I'd uninstall it and find another piece of software that did.  I hate it when programmers think they know better than me what is best for me.

### EDIT:

I have reformatted my hard drive to get rid of such applications.  For example, rootkits.

Comment: your company did not buy this software and installed it on your machine because they wanted to? was the case that you are describing? I doubt it.

Answer (score 11):

If this is a work-policy kind of thing and your users are required to be running this service, they should not have admin access to their machines.  Admin users can do anything to the box.

(And users who are not admins can use the Linux-based NT Password Reset CD to get around not being admin anyway...)

Comment: Good point.  The problem isn't with the software, its with the work policies.

Comment: I agree but those are the constraints set by the customer.

Comment: If the customer wants to do this, they need to stop giving their employees admin access.  Simply instruct them that admins can do anything to their computer, and you will not be supporting any sort of workaround involving users with admin access, since they will be able to disable it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

> What is "standard" approach to solving this issue?

The standard approach is **NOT** to do things behind the users back.

- If your service should be on then warn the user when they turn it off.
- If you are persistent warn them when the machine boots (and it is not on)
- If you want to be annoying warn them when they log in (and it is not on)

If you want your software crushed warn more often or explicitly do stuff the user does not want you to do.

Now if you are the IT department of your company.
Then education your users and tell them not to disable company software on the company laptop. Doing so should result in disciplinary action. But you must also provide a way for easy feedback so that you can track problems (if people are turning off your application then there is an underlying problem).

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to flood every single place from where an application can be started with your "hidden" application. Even if your users can find some places, they will miss others. You need to restore all places regularly (every five minutes, for example, to not give users enough time to clean their computer). The places include, but are not limited to:

- All autoruns: Run and RunOnce in Registry (both HKCU and HKLM); autorun from the Start menu.
- Winlogon scripts.
- Task scheduler.
- Explorer extensions: shell extensions, toolbars etc.
- Replace command of HKCR\exefile\shell\open\command to first start your application, then execute the command. You can do this with .bat, .cmd files etc.
- A lot of other places. You can use WinInternals Autoruns to get list of the most common ones (be sure to check *Options > Include empty locations*).

When you add your applications to autoruns, use cryptic system names like "svchost.exe". Put your application into system folders. Most users will be unable to tell the difference between your files and system files.

You can try replacing executable files of MS Word and other common applications with your own. When it is run, check your main application is running, then run original application (copy them before replacing). Be sure to extract icons from applications you replace and use them.

You can use multiple applications/services. If one is stopped, another one notices it and executes it again. So they protect each other.

Comment: Nice, the authoritative guide on how to write a virus and other malware.

Comment: I'd probably give this +1 if it was phrased "criminals do this" rather than "you can do this". Accurate information about appalling practices might still be useful to non-criminals too...

Comment: this is software is installed on the traveling laptops, by the administrator. It is a choice that the company as a whole has made. It is very much like the virus scan that I have running on my office machine. I can not take disable it because that is company policy. The uninstall is password protected...

Comment: @reza: Your company failed when they gave the user admin rights. You have a contradiction of goals: If you want them to **administrate** the computer, they **control** it. Yet you want to control them.

Comment: Legitimate applications do not name themselves "svchost".  Flagged for moderator attention

Comment: Oh come on people, have a sense of humour!  This is clearly a post in the same vein as the famous Paul Chambers tweet:

Crap! Robin Hood airport is closed. You've got a week and a bit to get your s**t together otherwise I'm blowing the airport sky high!

Comment: @EboMike I just decided it's about time to get [Peer Pressure](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge.

Comment: Technically this is correct. All the other answers are "don't do this it's stupid" which is also correct. But I find it interesting that the only one which contains the requested information is downvoted. It's true that usually malware does this and you shouldn't but then downvote the question.

Comment: @Athari too bad that folk are now voting this post back up!!

Comment: @stribika: It's a common paradigm in SO - I got downvoted several times when I answered exactly what the question asked for since the question was flawed. SO's philosophy is to direct misguided questions to the proper answer, or, as I was told, "don't give people a gun when they want to shoot themselves in the foot". Actually, I'm happy to provide the firearm if someone wants to perform a li'l bit of foot-shooting, but again, it seems to be SO's general attitude to discourage that, so I'm going with the program.

Comment: Answers are generally up/downvoted based on whether they are *good answers*, not whether or not they tell the OP what he wants to hear. This answer may tell the OP what he wants to hear, but it is still terrible advice, and hence it gets downvoted. The goal with SO is to get better programmers after all. The answers we give should aid that goal, and telling people how to write software that breaks every rule and drives the user mad isn't going to get us there.

Comment: @EboMike:  If by that rant you mean to say that SO's philosophy is to teach good programming practices, even to those who don't realize they are doing something wrong, then yes, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

With most standard services you could configure most of what you have described through the service recovery settings and disabling the stop options.

So what makes you want stricter control over your service?

For example your making a (security?) 'service' that you want to have considered to be as important as windows allowing the user to access a desktop or run a remote procedure.

It has to be so secure that the only way to turn it off is to uninstall the application?
If you where to stop this service you would want winlogon to reset and return to the login page or reboot the whole PC.

See corporate desktop management tools (like Novell Xen)

Comment: can I disable the disable feature of our service? That would do it.